# MySQL field type for storing decimals

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a DB that will hold products with several "height" columns (in meters, for ex 7.79 or 12,8). Never more than 2 digits before and 2 after the decimal point. What field type should I use for this?

If I use decimal(2,2) an try to insert 7.79 in phpmyadmin I get an error saying Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column 'working_height' at row 1

I'll be using this DB for searching, so I have to be able to run a query like "select all products where height is great than 7".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

People will say to use [decimal(s, d](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html)) but how about storing the values as integers, in centimeters instead of meters? Easier to compare (no precision loss).

Just my two cents.

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for decimal(4,2) - in general, decimal(m,n) means m total digits, and n to the right of the decimal point. Docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html).

So a decimal(2,2) can store two total digits, both to the right of the decimal point.  This explains the error that you are seeing.

Answer (score 4):

Try DECIMAL(4,2) instead

Refer to: [MySQL Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)